# My mum is growing a baby!

Tags: phrase-request

Does this expression said by a child sound natural?

> My mum is growing a baby!

If not, could it be considered a stretch?

What could a child say other than i.e. in child's language

> She's pregnant

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely not something an adult would say, but it makes sense as something cute that a child might say (it seems like the kind of thing you would see in the Family Circus comic strip).

A more common alternatives to "pregnant" is "going to have a baby."

Comment: Thank you. By the way, I take it you've never heard it spoken in real life, have you?

Comment: no -- it definitely makes sense, it's not something people say but if you were writing a book and had a child say this it would make sense.

Comment: @learner [it's rare, but it's there](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=growing+a+baby&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cgrowing%20a%20baby%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgrowing%20a%20baby%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGrowing%20a%20baby%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Thank you @MaciejStachowski for the Google ngram link, sometimes I forget it is there!

Comment: I think you should ask a kid. The ten examples that I checked on the n-gram for the most recent years all had 'growing a baby' as a phrase used by adults.

Comment: The problem with ngram is that you don't know the context in which the phrase occurred. For all we know, it was "Of course, we'd never say "growing a baby' because being pregnant is not even remotely similar to raising produce or farming."

Comment: Although the Google Books Ngram Viewer charts are unfortunately based on a rather different treatment of the data than what you can directly query, [you *can* search Google Books itself for your n-grams](https://www.google.com/search?q="growing+a+baby"&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099) and not just plot the occurrences of n-grams in the corpus over time.  I assumed that CarSmack did so when they said they checked "ten examples".